# Create a one-second delay between requests in okhttp3

Tags: android, okhttp

Is there a solution to create a one second delay between the quests we send with Okhttp3?
This means, for example, if the user sent 10 requests, check if the previous request interval was one second by now, otherwise the app will wait for one second, then do the sending work.

I checked this link but it did not work:
[How can I queue up and delay retrofit requests to avoid hitting an api rate limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41309103/how-can-i-queue-up-and-delay-retrofit-requests-to-avoid-hitting-an-api-rate-limi)

Comment: It depends on your usage.  Thread.sleep? Or if you are using RxJava the delay operator?

Comment: I do not use rx java my friend. In which part of the okhttp code should I use the Thread.sleep? because I want there to be a 1 second delay for all my requests

Comment: Why not have it in your code?

Answer (score 0):

The shown examples in linked question didn't work for me too. So I made a research and found this [OkHttp Delay Interceptor library](https://github.com/pawel-schmidt/okhttp-delay-interceptor). You can just call `.addInterceptor(DelayInterceptor(Long, TimeUnit))` method on your's OkHttp client builder object to set a specific delay for requests.

Comment: Is it upstream delay or downstream delay?