# Queue download using Retrofit

Tags: android, download, queue, retrofit

I am trying to create a Queue manager for my Android app.

In my app, I show a list of videos in the RecyclerView. When the user clicks on any video, I download the video on the device. The download itself is working fine and I can even download multiple videos concurrently and show download progress for each download.

**The Issue:**
I want to download only 3 videos concurrently and put all the other download in the queue.

Here is my Retrofit service generator class:

```
object RetrofitInstance {

private val downloadRetrofit by lazy {
    val dispatcher = Dispatcher()
    dispatcher.maxRequestsPerHost = 1
    dispatcher.maxRequests = 3

    val client = OkHttpClient
        .Builder()
        .dispatcher(dispatcher)
        .build()

    Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .client(client)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
}

val downloadApi: Endpoints by lazy {
    downloadRetrofit.create(Endpoints::class.java)
}
}
```

And here is my endpoint interface class:

```
interface Endpoints {

@GET
@Streaming
suspend fun downloadFile(@Url fileURL: String): Response<ResponseBody>
}
```

And I am using Kotlin coroutine to start the download:

```
suspend fun startDownload(url: String, filePath: String) {
    val downloadService = RetrofitInstance.downloadApi.downloadFile(url)
    if (downloadService.isSuccessful) {
        saveFile(downloadService.body(), filePath)
    } else {
        // callback for error
    }
}
```

I also tried reducing the number of threads Retrofit could use by using `Dispatcher(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1))` but that didn't help as well. It still downloads all the files concurrently.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

### EDIT

Forgot to mention one thing. I am using a custom view for the recyclerView item. These custom views are managing their own downloading state by directly calling the Download class.

Comment: try something like using intercepter of okhttp https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41309103/how-can-i-queue-up-and-delay-retrofit-requests-to-avoid-hitting-an-api-rate-limi

Comment: if using rxjava look at https://medium.com/mindorks/rxjava2-demo2-downloading-songs-in-android-2ebf91ac3a9a

Comment: Hi @Sandeepdhiman, I have already checked the link and it isn't very reliable as it will put the request to sleep for some time whereas I am looking for a queue system. Thanks for referring though (y)

Comment: Hi @Raghunandan, I am not using RxJava but I will look into it, maybe it will give me some insight on how to resolve the issue.

Comment: you might want to look at this https://gist.github.com/objcode/7ab4e7b1df8acd88696cb0ccecad16f7#file-concurrencyhelpers-kt-L19 and https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/coroutines-on-android-part-iii-real-work-2ba8a2ec2f45. You can queue your requests using mutex check singlerunner

Comment: @Raghunandan Thanks! Looks like mutex is the one I'm looking for. I'll upvote your comment (y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to achieve it but I am still not sure if this is the most efficient way to do it. I used a singleton variable of ThreadPool. Here is what I did:

In my Download class, I created a companion object of ThreadPoolExecutor:

```
companion object {
    private val executor: ThreadPoolExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3) as ThreadPoolExecutor
}
```

Then I made the following changes in my startDownload function:

```
fun startDownloading(url: String, filePath: String) {
    downloadUtilImp.downloadQueued()

    runBlocking {
        downloadJob = launch(executor.asCoroutineDispatcher()) {
            val downloadService = RetrofitInstance.api.downloadFile(url)
            if (downloadService.isSuccessful) saveFile(downloadService.body(), filePath)
            else downloadUtilImp.downloadFailed(downloadService.errorBody().toString())
        }
    }
}
```

This code only downloads 3 videos at a time and queues all the other download requests.

I am still open to suggestions if there is a better way to do it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use CoroutineWorker to download videos in the background thread and handle a download queue.

1. Create the worker

```
class DownloadVideoWorker(
    private val context: Context,
    private val params: WorkerParameters,
    private val downloadApi: DownloadApi
) : CoroutineWorker(context, params) {

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        val videos = inputData.getStringArray(VIDEOS)
        //Download videos
        return success()
    }

    companion object {
        const val VIDEOS: String = "VIDEOS"
    
        fun enqueue(videos: Array<String>): LiveData<WorkInfo> {
            val downloadWorker = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<DownloadVideoWorker>()
                .setInputData(Data.Builder().putStringArray(VIDEOS, videos).build())
                .build()
            val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance()
            workManager.enqueue(downloadWorker)
            return workManager.getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(downloadWorker.id)
        }
    }
}
```

2. In your viewModel add function to call worker from your Fragment/Activity

```
class DownloadViewModel() : ViewModel() {
    private var listOfVideos: Array<String> // Videos urls

    fun downloadVideos(): LiveData<WorkInfo> {
        val videosToDownload = retrieveNextThreeVideos()
        return DownloadVideoWorker.enqueue(videos)
    }
    
    fun retrieveNextThreeVideos(): Array<String> {
        if(listOfVideos.size >= 3) {
            val videosToDownload = listOfVideos.subList(0, 3)
            videosToDownload.forEach { listOfVideos.remove(it) }
            return videosToDownload
        }
        return listOfVideos
    }
}
```

3. Observe LiveData and handle worker result

```
    fun downloadVideos() {
        documentsViewModel.downloadVideos().observe(this, Observer {
            when (it.state) {
                WorkInfo.State.SUCCEEDED -> {
                    downloadVideos()
                }
                WorkInfo.State.FAILED -> {
                    // Handle error result
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

NOTE: To learn more about Coroutine Worker, see: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/coroutineworker

Comment: Hi @JuanFraga, thank you for your answer. It looks like a very good approach but I can't use it, unfortunately. I forgot to mention one thing in my question (I'll add soon). I am using a custom view for items in RecyclerView. These CustomViews are managing their own downloading state by directly calling the Download class.