# Android: Not allow spam requests being called using Retrofit2

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have a case where some users end up in a loop of requesting `@GET` API call too often.
Too often = 10-20x every second.

Currently, I've not located the problem and it seems that it's not going to be an easy fix, but I was wondering, is there a possibility to set some kind of limitations on `Retrofit2`, where if the app goes into some kind of loop where single API request is called so many times, it actually ignores these requests, for instance, do 1-5x same requests in a second max. or something similar?

How could this be done (from a networking library settings perspective)? (Till I find the root cause, I'd like to protect backend)

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41309103/how-can-i-queue-up-and-delay-retrofit-requests-to-avoid-hitting-an-api-rate-limi, it's probably better you fix this serious bug though.

Answer (score 0):

According the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51999402/4862911) answer you can use dispatcher as below:

```
Dispatcher dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
dispatcher.setMaxRequests(1);

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .dispatcher(dispatcher)
            .build()
```

After then you will be able to send one request on a time.

Comment: If the app is using a lot of requests, will this limit specific request to send one at a time?
For instance, app uses: A, B, C, D requests and it looks like this A, A, A, B, A, C, D (async).
Result would be A, B, C, D?

Comment: i dont think so. as far as i understood this is only limiting the sending request in one second. So if you send 5 request in a second, no matter what end point you hit, then the first one will be send. @MaartinAndroid

but as i mentioned i am not sure. you can try and realize what will be happen.